# А какова этимология слова "пельмень"?

Tags: этимология

А какова этимология слова "пельмень"? По идее, это слово русское — ведь и блюдо русское.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я слышала, что и блюдо, и имя заимствованные. Из Википедии:

Пельмени были заимствованы севернорусским населением в середине 2 тысячелетия н. э. у летописной Перми — предков коми-пермяков (Пермь Великая) и зырян (Пермь Вычегодская). Русское слово пельме́ни является заимствованием из языка коми пельня́нь «хлебное ухо»: пель «ухо» + нянь «хлеб»[1][2]. Слово пельмени (также пельняни и др.) попало сначала в вятские, уральские и в целом в севернорусские говоры, и уже оттуда перешло в литературный русский язык.

Answer (score 1):

Этимологический словарь русского языка Фасмера даёт ту самую этимологию. Хотя я китайского не знаю, у меня была такая идея: возможно ли связь с китайским словом 麵 или 面 'паста', 'макароны', итд. Произносится вроде мян (miàn). По-английски есть разные названия типов пасты: chow mein, lo mein, ramen. В русском языке есть и другие позаимствования так назывемых "культурных слов" (Kulturwörter), на пример чугун.